# Managing multiple lists with multiple tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have approximately 2000 lines of data in the following format:

```
.
.
[(0, 1, 'Blank', ''), (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Ayiesha Woods'), (5, 10, 'DOB', 'July 2 , 1979'), (10, 13, 'LOC', 'Long Island'), (13, 16, 'LOC', 'New York')]
[(0, 1, 'Blank', ''), (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Craig Rivera'), (7, 12, 'DOB', 'October 10 , 1954'), (5, 7, 'LOC', 'Manhattan')]
[(0, 1, 'Blank', ''), (0, 4, 'NAME', 'Margery Pitt Durant'), (14, 16, 'LOC', 'Flint'), (6, 11, 'DOB', 'May 24 , 1887'), (16, 18, 'LOC', 'Michigan')]
[(0, 1, 'Blank', ''), (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Austin Watson'), (10, 13, 'LOC', 'Ann Arbor'), (13, 15, 'LOC', 'Michigan'), (4, 9, 'DOB', 'January 13 , 1992')]
[(0, 1, 'Blank', ''), (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Gary Spatz'), (5, 8, 'LOC', 'New York'), (16, 19, 'LOC', 'New York'), (19, 21, 'LOC', 'Miami'), (21, 23, 'LOC', 'Florida'), (8, 13, 'DOB', 'April 1 , 1951')]
.
.
.
```

They are basically many lists each of them containing details of people like name, dob, loc etc. inside respective tuples.

I want to extract name of all the people and their corresponding dob in the following format:

```
('Ayiesha Woods', 'DateOfBirth', 'July 2 , 1979')
('Craig Rivera', 'DateOfBirth', 'October 10 , 1954')
```

and so on..

This is my attempt:

```
temp = "DateOFBirth"
results = []

for n1 in text:
    for n2 in text:
        if n1 is not n2:
            if text[1][2] == 'NAME' and text[2][2] == 'DOB':
                rel = text[1][3], temp, text[2][3]
                print(rel)
            results.append(rel)
```

This will only output if the name tuple is at position 1 and date tuple is at position 2 in the list which is not always the case.

What do I do if I want to output the result irrespective of the position of the name tuple or date tuple in the list.

EDIT:

I have a list containing tuples like:

```
text = [(0, 1, 'Blank', ''), (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Vance Trimble'), (5, 7, 'LOC', 'Harrison'), (7, 9, 'LOC', 'Arkansas'), (9, 14, 'DOB', 'July 6 , 1913')]
```

I am looking to extract data in the following format:

```
('Vance Trimble', 'DateOFBirth', 'July 6 , 1913')
```

My code:

```
temp = "DateOFBirth"
if text[1][2] == 'NAME' and text[4][2] == 'DOB':
    rel = text[1][3], temp, text[4][3]
    print(rel)
```

Ho do i do this without having to hardcode like:

```
text[1][2] == 'NAME' and text[4][2] == 'DOB'
```

so that it searches the list by itself for 'NAME' and 'DOB' and gets the output.

Comment: could you please give accurate lists to try out your code, cause with the info you provide it is not easy to reproduce your code or even understand what you specifically asking...

Comment: What's your data type? and how you've got `text`? what's its format?

Comment: I'm not sure what the nested for loops are all about. Perhaps there is some other requirement you didn't mention?

Comment: i have edited my question. with a simpler version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
temp = "DateOFBirth"
text = [(0, 1, 'Blank', ''), (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Vance Trimble'), (5, 7, 'LOC', 'Harrison'), (7, 9, 'LOC', 'Arkansas'), (9, 14, 'DOB', 'July 6 , 1913')]
rel = []
for i in text:
    if 'NAME' in i:
        rel.append(i[i.index('NAME')+1])    
        rel.append(temp)    
    elif 'DOB' in i:
        rel.append(i[i.index('DOB')+1])         
print rel
# result:
# ['Vance Trimble', 'DateOFBirth', 'July 6 , 1913']
```

In this way the results are independent of the location of the items 'NAME' and 'DOB' in the tuples, but only if e.g. the actual name always follows the 'tag' `'NAME'`, as it is here: `(0, 3, 'NAME', 'Vance Trimble')`, where the actual name follows the `NAME`.

Answer (score 2):

Break down the problem into simple steps:

1. Loop through the list of records.
2. Each record consists of a list of tuples in somewhat arbitrary order.
3. Look through each tuple in the record (loop) looking for NAME and DOB.
4. When found add the desired data from the tuple to result.

Viola!

```
results = []
for rec in records:
    result = ["", "DateOfBirth", ""]
    for item in rec:
        if "NAME" in item:
            result[0] = item[3]
        elif "DOB" in item:
            result[2] = item[3]
    results.append(tuple(result))
print(results)
```

Comment: Use assignment `=`, not equality `==`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing a helper function which retrieves the information from your data. I am also assuming that you are working with a list of lists of tuples.

```
 test_list = [[(0, 1, 'Blank', ''),
  (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Ayiesha Woods'),
  (5, 10, 'DOB', 'July 2 , 1979'),
  (10, 13, 'LOC', 'Long Island'),
  (13, 16, 'LOC', 'New York')],
 [(0, 1, 'Blank', ''),
  (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Craig Rivera'),
  (7, 12, 'DOB', 'October 10 , 1954'),
  (5, 7, 'LOC', 'Manhattan')],
 [(0, 1, 'Blank', ''),
  (0, 4, 'NAME', 'Margery Pitt Durant'),
  (14, 16, 'LOC', 'Flint'),
  (6, 11, 'DOB', 'May 24 , 1887'),
  (16, 18, 'LOC', 'Michigan')],
 [(0, 1, 'Blank', ''),
  (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Austin Watson'),
  (10, 13, 'LOC', 'Ann Arbor'),
  (13, 15, 'LOC', 'Michigan'),
  (4, 9, 'DOB', 'January 13 , 1992')],
 [(0, 1, 'Blank', ''),
  (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Gary Spatz'),
  (5, 8, 'LOC', 'New York'),
  (16, 19, 'LOC', 'New York'),
  (19, 21, 'LOC', 'Miami'),
  (21, 23, 'LOC', 'Florida'),
  (8, 13, 'DOB', 'April 1 , 1951')]]

#Helper function
def get_person_info(lst):
    person_name = list(filter(lambda x: 'NAME' in x, lst))[0][3:]
    person_dob = list(filter(lambda x: 'DOB' in x, lst))[0][2:4]
    return person_name + person_dob

#Use it with map
list(map(get_person_info, test_list))
```

Output:

```
[('Ayiesha Woods', 'DOB', 'July 2 , 1979'),
 ('Craig Rivera', 'DOB', 'October 10 , 1954'),
 ('Margery Pitt Durant', 'DOB', 'May 24 , 1887'),
 ('Austin Watson', 'DOB', 'January 13 , 1992'),
 ('Gary Spatz', 'DOB', 'April 1 , 1951')]
```

Testing the helper function with `text`:

```
text = [(0, 1, 'Blank', ''), (0, 3, 'NAME', 'Vance Trimble'), (5, 7, 'LOC', 'Harrison'), (7, 9, 'LOC', 'Arkansas'), (9, 14, 'DOB', 'July 6 , 1913')]

get_person_info(text)

## ('Vance Trimble', 'DOB', 'July 6 , 1913')
```

You can easily replace 'DOB' with 'DateOFBirth'.

Comment: What are the list indecies doing on the end of the filter lines? I can't seem to figure them out.

Comment: `filter` does not return a list in `Python3`; so you have to coerce the output into a list, grab the first element (the `tuple` indexed at 0).

Comment: Right. I meant the slice. [3:]? I might be a little dense.

Comment: It's to get a `tuple`; so that I can use `+` later to join the name and dob. If I had only sliced the 3rd element, it would have returned a string, not a `tuple`.

Comment: Ahhhh. The light of understanding dawns. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I am glad the code makes sense now. Thanks for helping me explain it to myself, as well.